# How to make a table column case insensitive in Firebird server?

Tags: firebird

How to make a table column case insensitive in Firebird server?

I am using this code, but it's not working..

```
con.opne();
cmd = new FbCommand("ALTER TABLE asco ALTER COLUMN Final_Model VARCHAR(30) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS NULL", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.close();
```

Error:

```
ERROR:Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 43
VARCHAR
```

Comment: I think it's not possible to alter the collation with `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN`. If the table is not empty, you probably have to add a new column with the desired collation, copy the data into it. And then drop the existing column. (or use a temporary table for that).

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your statement. First of all, according to the Interbase 6.0 language reference (available from the [documentation section of the Firebird site](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/)) section `ALTER TABLE` (page 28), the correct syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE table <operation> [, <operation> ...];
<operation> = {...
  | ALTER [COLUMN] column_name <alt_col_clause>
  ...}
<alt_col_clause> = {...
  | TYPE new_col_datatype
  ...}
```

Notice that `new_col_datatype` is not further expanded upon (`datatype` is however on page 29). In other words the statement should at least be:

```
ALTER TABLE asco 
  ALTER COLUMN Final_Model 
    TYPE VARCHAR(30)
```

Note the `TYPE` between the column name and the datatype. The order of the BNF productions in the Language Reference could make you think that you can also alter the collation of a column, unfortunately you can't.

So if you want to change the collation, you will have to create a new column with the right collation, copy the content and then drop the old column (and rename the new column to the name of the old). See also [this thread on the Firebird-support list](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-support/2009/1/99893.html).

And finally I want to point out that 1) `Latin1_General_CS_AS` is a case **sensitive** collation and not insensitive as stated in your question and 2) Firebird does not know the collation `Latin1_General_CS_AS` (the closest to what you need is probably the default collations `WIN_PTBR` or `FR_FR_CI_AI`, otherwise you can create one yourself using [`CREATE COLLATION`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-collation-create)).